# Error processing route when using modelFor in model hook

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a route structure as follows:

```
this.route('brands', function() {
  this.route('brand', { path: ':brand_id' }, function() {
    this.route('items', function() {
      this.route('item', { path: ':item_id' });
    });
  });
});
```

Inside my `items` route I have the following model hook:

```
var brand = this.modelFor('brands.brand');
return brand.get('items');
```

When I start at the brand route and navigate towards an item route and then back to the items page, everything is fine. But, when I refresh at an item route and navigate back to the items route, `Error while processing route: brands.brand.items.index` is thrown.

Ember isn't really helping here with a meaningful error message. All I can see is some arcane rejected promises like:

`Router: 'application.brands.brands.brand.brands.brand.items.brands.brand.items.index': Resolve handler`.

---

**I tracked it down to these three possible solutions**

1) Use the following model hook on `items`:

```
let brand = this.modelFor('brands.brand')
return this.store.find('item', { brand: brand.id });
```

2) Comment out the `brand` relationship on the `item` model.

<s>3) Move the file 'brands/brand/items/index/route.js' to 'brands/brand/items/route.js'.</s> *Update: Doesn't work.*

I'm using Ember 1.12.0 with Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.16.1.

---

**Code**

```
// routes.js
this.route('brands', function() {
  this.route('brand', { path: ':brand_id' }, function() {
    this.route('items', function() {
      this.route('item', { path: ':item_id' });
    });
  });
});

// pods/brands/index/route.js
Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('brand');
  }
})

// pods/brands/brand/route.js
Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('brand', params.brand_id);
  }
});

// pods/brands/brand/items/index/route.js
Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    var brand = this.modelFor('brands.brand');
    return brand.get('items');
  }
});

// pods/brands/brand/items/item/route.js
Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('item', params.question_id);
  }
});

// models/brand.js
DS.Model.extend({
  //...
  items: DS.hasMany('item', { async: true })
});

// models/item.js
DS.Model.extend({
  //...
  brand: DS.belongsTo('brand', { async: true })
});
```

**Error**

```
Error while processing route: brands.brand.items.index
  logError @ ember.debug.js:23713
  defaultActionHandlers.error @ ember.debug.js:23656
  triggerEvent @ ember.debug.js:23769
  trigger @ ember.debug.js:44997
  Transition.trigger @ ember.debug.js:44822
  (anonymous function) @ ember.debug.js:44627
  tryCatch @ ember.debug.js:45439
  invokeCallback @ ember.debug.js:45451
  publish @ ember.debug.js:45422
  publishRejection @ ember.debug.js:45364
  (anonymous function) @ ember.debug.js:26472
  Queue.invoke @ ember.debug.js:878
  Queue.flush @ ember.debug.js:943
  DeferredActionQueues.flush @ ember.debug.js:748
  Backburner.end @ ember.debug.js:173
  Backburner.run @ ember.debug.js:228
  Backburner.join @ ember.debug.js:247
  run.join @ ember.debug.js:15904
  exports.default.EmberObject.default.extend._bubbleEvent @ ember.debug.js:36760
  (anonymous function) @ ember.debug.js:36710
  jQuery.event.dispatch @ jquery.js:4670
  jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle @ jquery.js:4338
```

Comment: Can't  you give a more complete snapshot of your code rather than selected snippets here and there? Usually the debug version of ember spits out more info than just "error while processing route".

Comment: I added more code that I think is relevant to the problem :). Unfortunately the error is very vague. I added it to the question as well. I almost seems like a production-like error, even though I'm running it using `ember serve`.

Comment: something is clearly wrong with your items route.  item works fine because it knows to get its model based on the id in url.  items fails because it relies on brands and brand to be resolved.  (edit) which may not be the case after a refresh.

Comment: There is not much going on in those routes really. I tried switching to a fixture adapter, and the problem doesn't occur there. Could this be a problem with a third party adapter? I'm using the https://github.com/kurko/ember-json-api adapter.

Comment: I added logging to the `model` hooks and each one from the base of the routing tree is called. So I guess that brands and brand are being resolved. I confirmed this by looking at the API requests log.